# Angular CLI disable html form if previous option not selected?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, select

I have a form that has a few select fields populated with options.

```
    <form [formGroup]="selectVehicleForm">
        
    <select formControlName="Manufacturer">
    <option *ngFor='let cars of cars$'>{{cars.Manufacturer}}</option>
    </select>

     <select formControlName="Model">
     <option *ngFor='let cars of cars$'>{{cars.Model}}</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

My question - how can I disable my "Model" field as long as a user has nothing selected in "Manufacturer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this (not tested) :

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.selectVehicleForm = this.fb.group({
    Manufacturer: [],
    Model: [{ value: '', disabled: true }]
  )};

  this.selectVehicleForm.get('Manufacturer').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) {
      this.selectVehicleForm.get('Model').enable();
    } else {
      this.selectVehicleForm.get('Model').reset('');
      this.selectVehicleForm.get('Model').disable();
    }
    this.selectVehicleForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  })
}
```

Comment: Works well, thank you so much, marking as answer asap

Comment: Great ! Could you please mark it as resolved ? :D

Answer (score 1):

You can listen `(change)` on the `FormControl` `Manufacturer` and call `enable()/disable()` on the `FormControl` `Model`

See the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xy8urh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Relevant parts are :

**HTML**

```
  <select formControlName="Manufacturer" (change)="onChangeManufacturer($event)">
    <option *ngFor='let cars of cars$'>{{cars.Manufacturer}}</option>
  </select>
```

**Typescript**

```
  selectVehicleForm = new FormGroup({
    Manufacturer: new FormControl(),
    Model: new FormControl(),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectVehicleForm.controls['Model'].disable();
  }

  onChangeManufacturer(value) {
    const formControlModel = this.selectVehicleForm.controls['Model'];
    if(this.selectVehicleForm.controls['Manufacturer']) {
      formControlModel.enable();
    } else {
      formControlModel.disable();
    } 
  }
```